# matiasgagliano/guillotine Project as Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know if there's a vanilla JS version of the great guillotine project?

https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine

I really love the way how this thing works, but I wan't to use it without including the jQuery package. I already thought about remixing this project (in regard to the original writer of the project) and opening a new repo.

Maybe there are other people here on SOF doing something in cooperation with me.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts/information!

Answer (score 0):

As a mootools class, probably closer to vanilla that jQuery. Bits of weirdness in it, it was a rush job and I haven't improved or refactored. Fires the onChanged event each time the data (x,y,angle etc) is updated/changed.

```
var guillotine = new Class({

Implements: [Options, Events],

changed: function(){
    this.fireEvent('changed');
},

options : {

test: 'whatever',

defaults : {
    width: 250,
    height: 300,
    zoomStep: 0.1,
    init: null,
    eventOnChange: null,
    onChange: null
}


},

initialize : function(element, options) {

    this.setOptions(options);

    console.log(this.options.test);

    this.img = $(element)

    this.zoomInFactor = 1 + this.options.defaults.zoomStep;
    this.zoomOutFactor = 1 / this.zoomInFactor;
    this.width = this.height = this.left = this.top = this.angle = this.myDragStart = this.myDragEnd = 0;

    this.data = {
        scale: 1,
        angle: 0,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        w: this.options.defaults.width,
        h: this.options.defaults.height
    };


    //set hardware acceleration on for the element given
    this.img.setStyles({'-webkit-perspective': 1000, 'perspective': 1000, '-webkit-backface-visibility': 'hidden', 'backface-visibility': 'hidden' });



    //do the element creation
    //wrap the existing img up in the new divs


        if(this.img.get('tag') === 'img'){

            if (this.img.naturalWidth) {
                width = this.img.naturalWidth;
                height = this.img.naturalHeight;

            } else {
                this.img.addClass('guillotine-sample');
                width = this.img.width;
                height = this.img.height;
                this.img.removeClass('guillotine-sample');
            }


        } else {

        width = this.img.width;
        height = this.img.height;

        };  

        //why do they create this ratio of widths


      this.width = width / this.options.defaults.width;
      this.height = height / this.options.defaults.height;

        //so now we have the natural width of the image that is being used
        //including the ratio

        //this.img.width = width / this.options.defaults.width;
        //this.img.height = height / this.options.defaults.height;

        //new canvas element has to have the raio width * 100 %

        this.canvas = new Element('div',{
            id: 'canvas',
            'class': 'guillotine-canvas',
            styles : {
                width: (width / this.options.defaults.width) * 100 + '%',
                height: (height / this.options.defaults.height) * 100 + '%',
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }
        }).wraps(this.img.id);

        this.window = new Element('div',{
            'class': 'guillotine-window',
            styles : {
                width: '100%',
                height: 'auto',
                'padding-top': this.options.defaults.height / this.options.defaults.width * 100 + '%'
            }
        }).wraps(this.canvas);  



        //setup the dragging of the canvas

        this.myDrag = new Drag('canvas', {

            snap: 0,



            onComplete: function(el){

                //need the figures in percentages not the px


                containerDimensions = this.window.getSize()

                myLeft = el.getPosition(this.window).x / containerDimensions.x;
                myTop = el.getPosition(this.window).y / containerDimensions.y;

                this.offset(-myLeft, -myTop);

                //this.canvas.setStyle('left' , (myLeft * 100) + '%')
                //this.canvas.setStyle('top' , (myTop * 100) + '%')


            }.bind(this)
        });         

    this.fireEvent('imageChange', this.data);
},

//functions


fit : function(){

    var prevWidth, relativeRatio, newWidth, newHeight;

    prevWidth = this.width;

    relativeRatio = this.height / this.width

    if (relativeRatio > 1) {
        this.width = 1;
        this.height = relativeRatio;
      } else {
        this.width = 1 / relativeRatio;
        this.height = 1;
      }


    this.canvas.setStyle('width' , (this.width * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
    this.canvas.setStyle('height' , (this.height * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');

    //set the data container to the scale unit use the previous width above

    this.offset((this.width - 1) / 2, (this.height - 1) / 2);

    this.data.scale *= this.width / prevWidth;

    this.fireEvent('changed');


},


zoom : function(direction) {


    if(direction == 'in'){
        factor = this.zoomInFactor;
    }else if(direction == 'out'){
        factor = this.zoomOutFactor;
    }


    if (factor <= 0 || factor === 1) {
        return;
    }

    var w = this.width, h = this.height;

    if (w * factor > 0 && h * factor > 0) {
        //*= >> x = x * y
        this.width *= factor;
        this.height *= factor;
        this.canvas.setStyle('width', (this.width * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        this.canvas.setStyle('height' , (this.height * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        //set the record transformations
        this.data.scale *= factor;
    } else {
        this.fit();
        factor = this.width / w;
    }

    //now sort out the centre zoomStep
    var left = (this.left + 0.5) * factor - 0.5;
    var top = (this.top + 0.5) * factor - 0.5;

    this.offset(left,top);


},

rotate : function(angle) {

  var canvasRatio, glltRatio, h, w, _ref, _ref1, _ref2;


  //check if angle is a 90 degree unit
  if (!(angle !== 0 && angle % 90 === 0)) {
    return;
  }


  this.angle = (this.angle + angle) % 360;

  if (this.angle < 0) {
    this.angle = 360 + this.angle;
  }

  if (angle % 180 !== 0) {

    glltRatio = this.options.defaults.height / this.options.defaults.width;

    _ref = [this.height * glltRatio, this.width / glltRatio], this.width = _ref[0], this.height = _ref[1];

    if (this.width >= 1 && this.height >= 1) {
      this.canvas.setStyle('width' , this.width * 100 + '%');
      this.canvas.setStyle('height' , this.height * 100 + '%');
    } else {
      this.fit();
    }
  }


  _ref1 = [1, 1], w = _ref1[0], h = _ref1[1];

  if (this.angle % 180 !== 0) {
    canvasRatio = this.height / this.width * glltRatio;
    _ref2 = [canvasRatio, 1 / canvasRatio], w = _ref2[0], h = _ref2[1];
  }

  this.img.setStyles({
        'width' : w * 100 + '%',
        'height' : h * 100 + '%',
        'left' : (1 - w) / 2 * 100 + '%',
        'top' : (1 - h) / 2 * 100 + '%',
        transform : 'rotate(' + this.angle + 'deg)'
  })

    this.data.angle = this.angle;

    this.center();



},



center : function() {
    this.offset((this.width - 1) / 2, (this.height - 1) / 2);
},



offset : function(left,top) {

    if (left || left === 0) {
        if (left < 0) {
          //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
          //left = 0;
        }
        if (left > this.width - 1) {
          //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
          //left = this.width - 1;
        }

        this.canvas.setStyle('left' , (-left * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        this.left = left;
        this.data.x = Math.round(left * this.options.defaults.width);

    }


    if (top || top === 0) {

        if (top < 0) {
          //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
          //top = 0;
        }
        if (top > this.height - 1) {
          //I HAVE REMOVED THIS SO THAT WE CAN MOVE A SHRUNKEN IMAGE AROUND
          //top = this.height - 1;
        }

        this.canvas.setStyle('top' , (-top * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
        this.top = top;
        this.data.y = Math.round(top * this.options.defaults.height);
    }

    this.fireEvent('changed');

},

getData : function() {
  return this.data;
}
```

});